# How much of the surface of these equilateral triangles would be lit?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, polygons, projection

Consider an equilateral triangle $\Delta ABC$ in 3D with $A=(1,0,0)$, $B=(0,1,0)$ and $C=(0,0,1)$ as well as its mirror image $\Delta A'B'C'$ with $A'=-A$, $B'=-B$ and $C'=-C$. We assume that these triangles are "filled in" such that they can cast shadows under the light of a sun. Let the sun be infinitely far away in the direction $s\in\mathbb R^3$ such that it casts rays parallel to $-s$.

Depending on $s$, how much surface area of the triangles is lit and how much is shadowed?

I can, for a given $s$, project the triangles onto the plane $H_s$ through the origin with normal $s$, choose a coordinate system on it, use the Sutherland-Hodgman algorithm to clip both triangles with respect to each other and compute the area of the resulting convex polygon. Unfortunately, I have trouble finding an analytical expression for the area of this polygon depending on $s$.

Comment: see [Area of a polygon with given n ordered vertices](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/area-of-a-polygon-with-given-n-ordered-vertices) for example. If you need more, just search for "area of a polygon from vertices"

Comment: Sorry I probably wasn't clear here: I know how to calculate the area of a polygon. But I have trouble finding an analytic expression of the area of this special polygon depending on the direction of the sun $s$.

Comment: You project the two triangles onto a single plane, as you've discussed, then find the $0$ to $6$ points of intersection between the sides of the two triangles. These form the vertices of the polygon, whose area is found by the indicated method. There is not going to be one nice formula that does it all, because of the varying possibilities for the number of intersections. At best you probably would have seven different formulas (one of them $A = 0$) depending on various initial conditions. But the algorithm is straight-forward.